# How to automatically apply a line break to a long string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to embbed a base64 encoded PDF into my PowerShell script. This works so far without an issue. However this results in one long line within my script.

So the question is:

How can I convert my very long base64 string into a string containing line breaks with backticks without having to manually add them?

This one...

```
$test = "asdfghjklmasdfghjklmasdfghjklmasdfghjklmasdfghjklm"
```

Should become this one...

```
$test = "asdfghjklm`
asdfghjklm`
asdfghjklm`
asdfghjklm`
asdfghjklm"
```

Comment: ...what are you splitting on? #Confused

Comment: I would like to split on num of characters. So let's say include a backtick after every 20 characters. I hope it got clearer what I am trying to achieve

Comment: So far I was using Notepad++ by creating a macro that added a backtick after a specific num of characters. But I wondering how this can be done via PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the backticks? Inserting newlines into a base64-encoded string should not make any difference.

```
PS C:\> $s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
PS C:\> $b64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($s))
PS C:\> $b64
TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdC4=
PS C:\> $b64w = $b64 -replace '.{10}', "`$&`n"
PS C:\> $b64w
TG9yZW0gaX
BzdW0gZG9s
b3Igc2l0IG
FtZXQsIGNv
bnNlY3RldH
VyIGFkaXBp
c2NpbmcgZW
xpdC4=
PS C:\> [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($b64w))
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
PS C:\> [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($b64))
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: `-replace ".{10}", "```n"`

Comment: Thx for your reply Ansgar. I think my question was very unclear. I am reading pdf document into a byte array `[byte[]]$data = Get-Content -Path myfile.pdf -Encoding Byte` and later convert it to `[string]$b64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($data)` Now I would like to put that string/PDF file into my script. But I dont want it to be presented on one line and don't want to add the backticks manually.

Comment: Ah, now  I see. What you are saying is that there is no need for backticks at all..

Comment: @Matze Exactly.

Comment: @gvee I'm questioning the need for the additional backticks.